# My TextView shows empty when the application starts

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new at Kotlin, and I'm doing a simple app where the user writes something on `EditText`, presses a button then the app proceeds to show that text on `SecondActivity`, on that `SecondActivity` the user can do exactly the same thing, but on the `FirstActivity` (the one who shows up on the user starts the app) there are on `EditText` with "Welcome" text for default that shows empty when the application starts, this started to happen when I implement the text to be substituted by what the user writes on the `SecondActivity`

Here's the code for the `FirtActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nomeUser)
        

        val nameEntered = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameEntered)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener{

            val name = nameEntered.text.toString()

            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NomeEscrito::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("Name", name)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val intent = intent
        val name = intent.getStringExtra("Name")



        result.text = name


    }
}
```

And here's the code for the `SecondActivity`

```
class NomeEscrito : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nome_escrito)

        val intent = intent
        val name = intent.getStringExtra("Name")

        val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)

        result.text = name

        val wordEntered = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textPhrase)
        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)

        button2.setOnClickListener{

            val name2 = wordEntered.text.toString()

            val intent2 = Intent(this@NomeEscrito, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent2.putExtra("Name", name2)
            startActivity(intent2)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please separate out the key "Name" for both activities. make it unique and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following line of your `FirstActivity`:

```kotlin
    val name = intent.getStringExtra("Name")
```

When you open up the app for the first time, there is no data in the `intent`. As a result, it returns an empty string.

You can do the a check for empty string before setting your `EditText` text to avoid this situation:

```kotlin
    if (!name.isNullOrBlank()) {
        result.text = name
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose different keys in getStringExtra in both intent data passing